# making the menu stay and not disappear on hovering out of the area

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a header with a menu to its side, right now the menu gets displayed by dropping down once I hove on the arrow on the side of header and disappears once I move my cursor out of the menu dropdown area.

How do I make the menu stay until I click like the arrow button on the top again or have a button in the menu like 'ok' which will slide up the menu?

Comment: Can you post your code or a live example?

Comment: can you start a jsfiddle with your code. There simply isn't enough info here to help you out.

Comment: I will be trying to upload it in jsfiddle, but its tricky cause the js is part of a compete template skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mousenter event to show the menu. Then use the click event of another element to hide the contents. Without your html/css it is a crapshoot determining the exact selectors and code that should be used.

http://jsfiddle.net/4Jn6q/

```
<div id="a">
    <span>X</span>
    <div>Some content to show</div>
</div>
```

```
$('#a').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children().slideDown();
});

$('span').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children().slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will be trying this out. I can upload my code but its a whole template skin with lot of js and css dependencies.